# python not in command line even though it is in path

Tags: python, windows, command-line, path

When I type 'python' at the command line it says ''python' is not recognized as an internal or external command...'

I have Python in both User and System paths. In the past I have been able to run python from the command line, but suddenly today I can't.

I'm using Windows 7 32-bit.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks

Comment: `echo %PATH%` What's the result?

Comment: C:\Python27;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;Python27\Scripts;C:\OpenSSL-Win32;

Comment: so solution was you didn't have python.exe so had to reinstall.   You'd have found that with basic troubleshooting, by trying to run python.exe from its location, without the path and seeing if that worked. it's a basic step.

Comment: Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13596505/6521116)

Answer (score 3):

This could be a duplicate answer, but the following steps has worked for me.

Note: *This is in the case of **Anaconda** is installed instead of vanilla Python in **Windows environment**.*

**Under System variables:**

1. Create a variable

> PYTHONHOME = C:\Users\username\Anaconda3

2. Add the below 2 entries under PATH system variable:

> %PYTHONHOME%
>
> C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Scripts

3. Close the command prompt if opened earlier and try any python command
   (Note: no need to restart the OS):

> example: python --version
>   output:  Python 3.7.1

Hope this was useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The python install directory on Windows should have the following files (ignore the pyscopg and pillow files):

[image: Python directory listing]

Your `PATH` environment variable should be like the below if you have install Python2 at the default location:

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\
```

You should also have the following in `PATHEXT`:

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

I noticed in your environment variables you have `Python27\Scripts;` which is not correct.  Try fixing that, and you'll have to close any command prompts if you change any environment variables. If the settings are as the above and you still can't run Python, do a re-install.

Comment: Seems to be paramount that Python37\Scripts\ is present. +1

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that you installed python in the default location.

try adding this into your system environments.

```
name : PYTHONPATH
value: C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\include;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

Note: when you create a PYTHONPATH environment variable it might effect some other application to forcefully use this version of python instead their own.

Comment: PYTHONPATH won't help with finding the python.exe executable.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem in the `PATH` environment variable. To confirm that, in `cmd` try the following:

If you are using Python 2.7:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27
```

If you are using Python 3.3:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python33
```

And then: `python something`

Comment: The output is the same ''python' is not recognized as an internal or external command...'

Comment: could you check if you have `python.exe` inside this folder `c:\Python27`

Answer (score 0):

`python` is clearly **NOT** in your `PATH` variable. You can confirm this by looking at the output of `echo %path%`.

Keep in mind that after editing the `PATH` variable using the control panel, you have to open a new terminal, as the setting will NOT be updated in existing terminals.

Another possibility is that you added the wrong path to the `PATH` variable. Verify it.

The bottom line is, if the directory of your `python.exe` is *really* in `PATH`, then running `python` will *really* work.

Comment: I don't seem to have a python.exe file, only pythonw.exe. Is this the problem? It's not in my recycle bin so I haven't accidentally deleted it.

Comment: I don't have a windows with me right now, but I'm pretty sure there should be a `python.exe`, and if you can't find it then something's wrong. Try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the command prompt window and opening again, then trying. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Most common mistake!!**

Developers **forget** to set this ***"C:\Python27\"*** in PATH variable assuming *"C:\Python27\Lib"* is enough.

**Both path should be present**

Answer (score -1):

Watch this video to install python correctly it was very helpful to me....

[How to Install Python Correctly](https://youtu.be/h6HPe98-SwI)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.